# Login dentro do javascript alert

Tags: php, javascript, login, alert

Tem como fazer um login com usuario e senha unicos dentro de um alert?

---

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Queria que fosse um codigo tipo esse, só nao sei colocar 2 prompt no msm popup

Answer (score 2):

Dentro de um `alert` não, mas você pode pegar informações do usuário através de um `prompt`.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/prompt

O problema é que esta não é uma forma muito "amigável" de se obter dados. Dê uma olhada se uma janela modal dentro da própria página atenderia aos seus requisitos:
http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals

Answer (score 1):

> *Isso não é exatamente "um login no alert", mas um login via `HTTP Basic Authentication`;*

Especificamente esta captura de tela parece ser de uma autenticação de `HTTP Basic Authentication`, inclusive pode fazer o login diretamente no URL como `http://nome:senha@site.com`.

[Você pode ler mais sobre isso aqui.](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/features.http-auth.php)

Se realmente deseja usar este tipo de autenticação e de quebra exibir dois formulários num único "alert" essa é a única solução, até onde saiba.

*Vale ressaltar que a exibição de tal "alert" pode mudar de acordo com o navegador, não necessariamente será mostrado desta forma.*

> Acredito que solução do @lfarroco, usando modal, é melhor e não exige mudanças no código em PHP, *ou são mudanças menores do que migrar para outro tipo de autenticação.*